# How to increase form loading speed if I set background image for my windows .net form?

Tags: forms, background-image

I have a problem with my forms: if I set the background image for my form, that form is very slow while loading. How can I overcome this problem? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

change the background image to jpg , and you should be through

Comment: sory sir,my question is not clear forgive me,i want background image for c#.net windows forms